# Метод forEach, нужно перебрать и вернуть массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы, foreach

Помогите разобраться, нужно чтобы в консоль вернуло массив a10, только те числа, которые меньше нуля, стали нулями, и вывелся массив.

```js
let a10 = [2, 13, 14, -7, 9, 5, 0, -2, 14];

function t10() {
  a10.forEach(item => {
    if (item < 0) {
      item = 0;
    }
    return item;
  });
  return a10;
}

document.querySelector('.b-10').onclick = () => {
  console.log(t10());
}
```

```html
<div class="b-10">Button</div>
```

Сейчас выводит: a10 = [2, 13, 14, -7, 9, 5, 0, -2, 14];
А нужно: a10 = [2, 13, 14, 0, 9, 5, 0, 0, 14];

Comment: foreach обязателен?

Comment: Да, именно forEch, по другому я могу сделать, нужно forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let a10 = [2, 13, 14, -7, 9, 5, 0, -2, 14];

a10.forEach((e, i) => {
  if (e < 0) a10[i] = 0;
});

console.log(a10);
```

Если не обязательно использовать `forEach`, то еще можно так:

```js
let a10 = [2, 13, 14, -7, 9, 5, 0, -2, 14];
let result = a10.map(e => e < 0 ? 0 : e);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: в forEach индексы можно передавать. 
a10.forEach((e,i) => {
  if (e < 0) a10[i] = 0;
});

Comment: @BearVorkuta Спасибо, поправил ответ!